# Auto-hide window at edge?

Tags: qt, qt4.8

Is there any guide on how to implement a auto hiding window, that collapse to a small piece of widget when it's placed at edge of screen

When mouse is hovering that small widget, it stretches to original widget (this could be done with Qt animation framework, not a problem here)

Answer (score 2):

You could check if your cursor and/or widget positions are in a N-pixel border, and then use a signal slot setup.The custom signal could be a timer elapsed event.

[Qt - Determine absolute widget and cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450595/qt-determine-absolute-widget-and-cursor-position)

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry

Be aware that multiscreen setups may not behave as expected, depending if they fuse your real screens to one, or treat them as seperate ones.

Comment: Thanks, how should I detect if mouse is over ? I didn't find a event to use

Comment: I think you will have to use a timer.