# QT : leaveEvent - Checking if the cursor is in region of a widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have  a class that inherits from `QLabel` this class implements the methods `mouseMoveEvent` and `leaveEvent`. When the mouse is over this widget a dialog box is displayed. However the dialog box only disappears if a mouse click occurs elsewhere. I want the dialog box to disappear when the mouse moves out of the reqion of this widget. I therefore thought about using the `leaveEvent` method which would call `dialog.hide()`. My question is how can I determine if the mouse cursor is in the region of a widget ?

Comment: You can get widget under cursor and compare it with your widget.

Comment: How do I get the widget under cursor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Qt - Determine absolute widget and cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450595/qt-determine-absolute-widget-and-cursor-position). Two ways are explained there.. using coordinates and using QWidget::underMouse().