# How can child widget capture the mouse event under such circumstance

Tags: qt, qmouseevent

I need to simulate drag and drop in Qt, but I'm facing a problem. Here is the simplified version of the problem:
[image]

here you can see the action I took. I pressed the mouse in the area of parent widget and moved it to a child widget, keeping pressing, I did not release the mouse until it is moved into the child Widget. However, I found that the child widget could not capture the mouse release event when I released the mouse. (Actually, I found it was not only mouse release event, but also any other mouse event which was supposed to happen when the mouse was in the child widget)

Could someone give me a simple solution to do this? Maybe It is because the widget structure in my project is quite complicated so there is something wrong stops the transfer of the mouse event.

Answer (score 0):

Try to accept mouse release event in parent widget, calculate mouse position,  compare to child widget, and notify child widget [Qt - Determine absolute widget and cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450595/qt-determine-absolute-widget-and-cursor-position).
Or use QDrag and QMimeData if you want to pass data.

Comment: Yes, I did it in this way, but I found the child widget cannot receive the event.