# How can find real coordinate in qt widget?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

```
event->scenePosition().x();
event->scenePosition().y();
```

This way I can only get the current position of the cursor on the widget. It just tells me what position on the screen I clicked. I want to get the actual location of the widget when I scroll or zoom the widget.

I made a mathematical formula to get the actual position when zoomed in , zoomed out or scrolled the widget and was manipulating the screen coordinates according to scaling and scrolling , but this was not giving me high precision. Are there special functions for this in Qt?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450595/qt-determine-absolute-widget-and-cursor-position) question might help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.